# Using a 15A Machine on a 20A circuit

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle

I've been working on some machines in hospitals.  The circuit is taking a 3A dip.  The electrician is saying "you've still got 15A on the circuit, so the machine doesn't see the dip"  is this true, or will the macine see the exact same dip as the circuit sees?

Comment: What does "taking a 3A dip" mean?

Comment: Machines don't "see" current. They see voltage and react to it. I'm not an electrician, but your question doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Then you didn't read it.  A 3A dip means that it is losing 3A.  The electrician is trying to use amps instead of voltage so that he doesn't have to repair the "non-dedicated" line.

Comment: "3A dip" is not a thing in electrical. You are either misheard what was said, are misusing electrical terms, or using some sort of in-house jargon.  Please [edit] to re-state it in plain English. Also please avoid [XY problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); state what the nature of **your** problem is.

Comment: @ForestOsbourn, electrical engineer here, and what you're saying doesn't make sense to me either.  It's not possible to 'lose' 3A -- if 3A flows into a device, 3A must flow out; that's physics.  'Trying to use amps instead of volts' doesn't make any sense either; they're two different things and you need both to extract useful electric power.  I think it's likely you're misunderstanding what your electrician is trying to say to you.

Comment: I've been multi tasking, so let me see if I can now clarify what is happening.  I have 3 machines (all the same) on 3 different floors, throwing the same exact errors. I DON'T  care about the amps, since the tolerance is so minimal on our machines, its moot.  It's  the a**hat electrician at the hospital that keeps spouting the amp crap.  I deal with voltage and dedicated/non-deicated outlets.   I sent a tech out yesterday to unplug ALL non essential equipment on the same room as 1 machine and have been monitoring it for 24 hours. No error codes.

Comment: We've been trying to tell this guy there's a voltage drain, but he keeps spouting amps, instead of voltage.  So its not us with the amos.  We just need to make him shut up about amps and listen to us about a voltage drop.

Comment: As far as 3A dip NOT being a thing.  Its wording.  Ya'll  can use whatever verbage you want.  I use dip (low or loss) and spike (high or gain).  Its just how I explain things.  If not understood, I explain afterwards.

Comment: I would say you are getting electrical noise affecting this device. The same reason we could not (can not ?) use cell phones around respirators because when the phone transmitted data it could cause the respirator to force a second breath, it had nothing to do with the power being delivered and the bio med techs were just like you blaming the power, try to work with the electrician as I can tell you 3 amps or 19 on a hospital circuit won’t cause a problem with voltage and that is easy to measure. You have 2 circuits in patient areas put this device on 1 circuit and the others on the 2nd Ckt.

Comment: Forest, please put all that in your question. It doesn't belong down here in comments. Thanks. (Also, multi-tasking is impossible. You've been _other_-tasking. :P )

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking and how you are relating the response are both wrong.
Hospital or not 3 amps is a tiny load even if you had a 5 amp breaker in the panel you would not see a drop in voltage until the breaker tripped this value is almost always above the stamped value on the breaker of 15a or 20a for almost all receptacles in a patient area.

Even if your loads in your area are fed from a small transformer like a 45kva to feed your work area you would see no difference in voltage. If this is in a patient area the transformer feeding the area will be much larger or that has been my experience in hospitals. If you measure the voltage then put a full load 15 or 20 amps on a circuit in a patient area you might see 1-2 volts dip but this is not a problem and well within the equipment tolerance.

Hospitals require coordinated systems so a small breaker will not cause a much larger breaker to trip. You may find during your joint commission inspections & certification some electrical testing being done (a lot was done prior to Y2K to verify emergency systems were in compliance). But a single device will not cause a problem unless the circuit is overloaded and the breaker trips, even then the voltage is normally at nominal.

Answer (score 0):

Another EE answering here.... Not really an 'answer' but too long for comments...

What I recommend is get a multimeter that measures AC volts (nearly all do and this doesn't have to be expensive).

Set it for the right scale (AC volts, and 200V range if it's not auto-ranging).  Stick the probes in the wall socket (Yes, it seems crazy but this is not unsafe if you're not stupid about it).   Then, measure the AC VOLTAGE.

What I "think" your electrician is saying is the machine consumes 3A, and the circuit is 15A, so you have 12A remaining before the breaker trips.   But that's only true if this one outlet leads back to the circuit breaker panel and there is NOTHING ELSE on the same circuit.  Anything else will eat into your 15A limit.  In a hospital that may be true (I have no idea) but in general, every circuit has multiple outlets.

As the machine kicks on & off, you may see a measurable drop in voltage. (Note: During any given day, if you measure nearly any outlet in the US, they'll vary from about 110-125, depending on electrical loading that time of day)

With modern wiring that's done 'to code', you won't see much drop at all... Couple volts maybe at most, possibly nothing at all.

If you see 10's of volts drop when the machine starts, then you do indeed have a power supply problem.  i.e. if your meter tells you the wall voltage is 90 or 100V.   If it's virtually no change, then bad power is likely not the source of your issue.